# Using couchdb.mapping and unable to set an attribute

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

Hi everyone and couchdb pros,

I have a mapping setup like such:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
  name= mapping.TextField()
  returned = mapping.DictField(mapping.Mapping.build(
    reason = mapping.TextField(),
    put_back = mapping.BooleanField()
  ))
```

I have a function called getById that takes an id and returns a product via:

```
return Product.load(db, id)
```

I have a problem:  When I load a particular product, and try to set the returned dictionary like such:

```
product = Product.getById("123")
product.returned
>>> {}
product.returned['reason'] = "Test"
product.returned
>>> {}
```

**NOTE:**
I only recently modified the model to have the "returned" key.  Old product objects which are obtained using getById, does not have the "returned" key in them.  Would this make a difference?  It shouldn't right, after all this is a document DB and it should be flexible right?

Why does product.returned still return me an empty dictionary after setting the "reason" attribute?

I did some debugging and realized that the product variable is of the form:

```
<Product u'f90173026e859c65cfa08496115bf7bf'@u'11-3ea1135ceb6361631cbb08471d15df1e' {u'name': u'Printer', u'subProducts': [], u'company': {u'id': u'HP', u'name': u'Hewlett-Packard'}, u'productType':.......>
```

What kind of result is this?  Is it a view result or is it a document?

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem.  Apparently, couchdb-python does not allow you to "create" new keys in documents that were created using a previous mapping model.  You would have to manually add the keys you want to all the documents first before you are able to set values for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, couchdb-python does not allow you to "create" new keys in documents that were created using a previous mapping model. You would have to manually add the keys you want to all the documents first before you are able to set values for them.